# How to integrate deep learning algorithms and tcp transmission video services

Tags: python, opencv, tcp, raspberry-pi, openvino

How to transfer real-time video processed by artificial intelligence to other platforms through tcp protocol.
I will use the computer as a server to accept the video, and the Raspberry Pi as a client to transmit the video.

I used OpenCV to implement real-time video transmission in the tcp protocol, and there is a complete and feasible object identification code (from https://github.com/PINTO0309/MobileNet-SSD-RealSense, thanks to the engineer PINTO0309).I receive video on the computer side (Windows system), object recognition and video transmission in the Raspberry Pi.

server

```py
import socket,time,cv2,numpy

def ReceiveVideo():
    address = ('193.169.4.155', 50000)
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.bind(address)

    s.listen(1)

    def recvall(sock, count):
        buf = b''
        while count:
            newbuf = sock.recv(count)
            if not newbuf: return None
            buf += newbuf
            count -= len(newbuf)
        return buf

    conn, addr = s.accept()
    print('connect from:'+str(addr))
    while 1:
        start = time.time()
        length = recvall(conn,16)
        stringData = recvall(conn, int(length))
        data = numpy.frombuffer(stringData, numpy.uint8)
        decimg=cv2.imdecode(data,cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
        cv2.imshow('SERVER',decimg)

        end = time.time()
        seconds = end - start
        fps  = 1/seconds;
        conn.send(bytes(str(int(fps)),encoding='utf-8'))
        k = cv2.waitKey(10)&0xff
        if k == 27:
            break
    s.close()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ReceiveVideo()
```

client

```py
import socket,cv2,numpy,time,sys

def SendVideo():
    address = ('193.169.4.155', 50000)
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    sock.connect(address)

    global capture

    capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    ret, frame = capture.read()
    encode_param=[int(cv2.IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY),15]

    while ret:

        time.sleep(0.01)

        result, imgencode = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame , encode_param)
        data = numpy.array(imgencode)
        stringData = data.tostring()

        sock.send(str.encode(str(len(stringData)).ljust(16)));

        sock.send(stringData);

        receive = sock.recv(1024)
        if len(receive):print(str(receive,encoding='utf-8'))

        ret, frame = capture.read()
        if cv2.waitKey(10) == 27:
            break
    sock.close()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    SendVideo()
```

Object identification code come from 
https://github.com/PINTO0309/MobileNet-SSD-RealSense/blob/master/MultiStickSSDwithPiCamera_OpenVINO_NCS2.py

I have encountered the following problem after modifying the code multiple times.

1. The video card after transmission is in the first frame.
2. Unable to transfer, the Raspberry Pi display error is `[Errno:32]Broken pipe`, and the pc side displays an error.

`OpenCV(3.4.2) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:356: error: (-215:Assertion failed) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function 'cv::imshow'`

I think second error means not getting the picture.

I finally want to realize real-time transmission of the recognized video to the computer.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic for capturing frame from video is wrong: i add some comment here

```
# you take one frame here
ret, frame = capture.read()
encode_param=[int(cv2.IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY),15]

# this will loop without taking any new frame
while ret:

    time.sleep(0.01)
    # as result: at the first frame will be encoded successfully
    # but from second times, frame will be double/tripple encoded and became un-usable
    result, imgencode = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame , encode_param)
    data = numpy.array(imgencode)
    stringData = data.tostring()
```

How to fix: change your code into something like this

```
encode_param=[int(cv2.IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY),15]

while(True):
    ret,frame = cap.read()
    result, imgencode = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame , encode_param)
    data = numpy.array(imgencode)
    stringData = data.tostring()
```